# Deploy New Route with Hawtio

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

I am trying to get started with Hawtio. How do I deploy a complete new route? I have Hawtio running on local tomcat. I can see in the Camel tab that two routes are predeployed. Then I go to the wiki tab and under the Spring folder, I can define additional camel configurations. But how do I get these configurations to be deployed so I can debug them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I already [answered this](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/How-to-Deploy-new-Camel-Context-with-Hawtio-td5742571.html#a5742576) on the Camel user list, but just in case folks are looking here; there are two options:

- the preferred option is to just use [Fabric](http://fuse.fusesource.org/fabric/) in [JBoss Fuse](http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse); which then automatically adds/updates/removes any camel routes created/edited/deleted via the Fuse management Console (which is based on hawtio). You can also take advantage of Fabric's support for rolling upgrades; so you can avoid changing all your containers at once and instead can move containers across to the new version or rollback etc. This all works across many containers with no single point of failure with full version control (a replicated git repository is used for all changes).
- if you're not using a Fuse Fabric and are using spring, [deploy this 
  jar](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/master/hawtio-watcher-spring-context) into your container (or add it as a dependency in your own WAR based on hawtio-default.war like the [sample war in hawtio](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/sample/pom.xml#L17). This then defaults to watching the [spring directory in the wiki](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/sample/pom.xml#L60) for any spring 
  XML files to deploy/update (including camel spring XML files, ActiveMQ 
  spring XML files, CXF spring XML files etc)
- here's an example project called [HawtioCamelWiki](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio-camel-wiki) which implements the above; using the spring watcher; its a single WAR which has a git based wiki internally so you can create and edit camel routes or spring XML files and they update on the fly

Answer (score 0):

[hawtio](http://hawt.io/) is a lightweight and modular web console with lots of [plugins](http://hawt.io/plugins/index.html). So you cannot create any  Route with hawtio itself. What you can do is create a standalone apache-camlel application and deploy as a war in the tomcat. Subsequently, you can get all the routes, Queues,Endpoints in the hawtio web console. 
Same way you can get the ActiveMQ in to the hawtio as well.

Hope this would help you.